# dhclient disconnects after few seconds

Tags: networking, 16.04, dhcp, wpa-supplicant, dhclient

I have been fighting with the interface of my ubuntu 16 lts server to connect to a wifi on startup. Currently I connect using wpa_supplicant and dhclient. 
If I do both manually, I get connected without problems.
When I want both to launch from startup, it seems wpa_supplicant is working fine but not dhclient.
I have set up the service with this configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description= DHCP Client
Before=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/sbin/dhclient wlp58s0 -v
ExecStop=/sbin/dhclient wlp58s0 -r

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And it seems it loads ok, connects and after some seconds it disconnects...

```
● dhclient.service - DHCP Client
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dhclient.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since mar 2020-04-07 16:13:06 CEST; 18min ago
  Process: 1862 ExecStop=/sbin/dhclient wlp58s0 -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 809 ExecStart=/sbin/dhclient wlp58s0 -v (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 809 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

abr 07 16:12:55 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[809]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.33 from 192.168.0.1
abr 07 16:12:55 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[809]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.33 on wlp58s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x42ec0a9b)
abr 07 16:12:55 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[809]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.33 from 192.168.0.1
abr 07 16:12:55 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[809]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.33 from 192.168.0.1
abr 07 16:12:55 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[809]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.33 from 192.168.0.1
abr 07 16:13:05 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[809]: bound to 192.168.0.33 -- renewal in 42791 seconds.
abr 07 16:13:05 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[809]: bound to 192.168.0.33 -- renewal in 42791 seconds.
abr 07 16:13:05 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[1862]: Killed old client process
abr 07 16:13:05 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[1862]: Killed old client process
abr 07 16:13:06 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[1862]: DHCPRELEASE on wlp58s0 to 192.168.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x636812e7)
```

More details in the syslog, it seems that the bound was ok

```
Apr  7 16:13:05 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[809]: bound to 192.168.0.33 -- renewal in 42791 seconds.
Apr  7 16:13:05 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[809]: bound to 192.168.0.33 -- renewal in 42791 seconds.
Apr  7 16:13:05 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[1862]: Killed old client process
Apr  7 16:13:05 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[1862]: Killed old client process
Apr  7 16:13:06 RB1B0-190625AB dhclient[1862]: DHCPRELEASE on wlp58s0 to 192.168.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x636812e7)
```

First of all it seems there are duplicated messages for everything. I don't think this is normal and I have been looking for possible duplicated processes, but it does not seem so.

Also, I paste my network/interfaces

```
allow-hotplug wlp58s0
iface wlp58s0 inet dhcp
wpa-driver wext
#pre-up killall -q wpa_supplicant
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```